# CSS inline won't let my text become responsive

Tags: css

For some reason my text just stays the same size no matter what I do, however.. the

```
<div id="box"> </div>
```

will respond to the the device it's being viewed on.. :/

Link to my website (it's only an intro page): view-source:http://www.lux-boutique.co.uk/

And the css page: http://www.lux-boutique.co.uk/lux.css

The text which I'd like to be responsive is:

```
<p style="height: 12%; padding:0px; margin: 0px; line-height: 1.1em; font-color: black; color: black; text-align: center; font: normal normal normal 350% 'Palatino Linotype',serif;">LUX <br><strike>BOUTIQUE</strike></style>
```

Any help is appreciated :D :D

Comment: Post the relevant code on your question, it shouldn't just be links to external resources.

Comment: Sorry, will update my original post.. I can see I may have come across as a lazy sod there!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your webpage and observed that you are using Media Queries for responsive text size. 
What exactly is happening there is on lux.css
line 77 You have : p - 2em !important

You need to override that . 
You can do two things:

Remove !important from there so other styles get applied ,
OR
Add important in media queries Overriding the style on p tag.
Ex:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1020px)
    p {
      font-size: 2em !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you separate your CSS from the HTML you should used media queries to make your font size responsive.

Your sites font size is set by either the visitors default browser styles or a size you set. The same font size will be used in all cases if media queries are not used.

Divs are the same however your div is simply doing as it is told (100% of whatever the screen size is).

[Documentation on media queries ›](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

[CSS Tricks showing how to use media queries for mobile sites ›](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)